# Why does LaTeX not render my gantt-diagram into pdf

Tags: latex, diagram, charts, tex, gantt-chart

is there anybody out there, with experiences about how to do a gantt-diagram / chart using latex.

I tryed it for a lot of hours today, lastly it worked switching outpout from pdf to dvi.
Maybe someone can tell me what to include, besides pst-gantt, and the normal pstricks stuff.

It showed more than 100 errors for 4 Tasks.. after switching to dvi there was a big 0.

i am using the whole distribution mitex .. upgradet to the newest version. stupidly i have the error log not avaible on this computer. but it was always the same error. i was using pst-gantt, outload missing packages.. hm errors will follow tomorrow morning

Comment: It would help if you told us what class or style you are using, what latex compiler, if you are able to get dvi or postscript output, what errors you are getting, etc... As it stands we could guess, but that is the best it would be.

Comment: pst-gantt loads ps-tricks, which is postscript, which pretty much means no pdflatex. that's why you got 0 errors when switching to DVI.

Comment: is there an option for pdf?
or an good method for dvi->pdf?

Comment: To get a DVI, you just run `latex`. To go from the DVI to a PDF, you first convert the DVI to PS using `dvips`, and then go from PS to PDF using `ps2pdf`.When I use LaTeX, I always run the cycle `latex; bibtex; latex; latex; dvips; ps2pdf`. This makes sure that all references are updated and that nothing is missing. (In the event that LaTeX still complains about reference issues, I may add another run or two of `latex` before the `dvips` command.)

Comment: There are DVI to PDF converters. The one on my old mac is called `dvipdfm`. Wether is will handle the specials from pstricks or not I couldn't say.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [`pst-gantt` README](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-gantt/) it looks like this depends on the [`pstricks` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/base/). I believe that the "ps" is for postscript and the functionality is implemented by generating DVI "special" commands; which means that you can't produce output pdf directly using `pdflatex`. You *can* get to PDF output, but [you must go by way of DVI](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=384). Either `source->DVI->PDF` or even `source->DVI->PS->PDF`.

Comment: @Sven, @Mica, @dmckee: A lot of code for pstricks works unchanged with pdftricks: it might be worth seeing if the two character change to pst-gantt.sty does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question when having trouble with pst-gantt and pdflatex. As others have pointed out you need to go via DVI, which honestly sucks if you have used pdflatex all the time.

So I did some search, and found this phantastic replacement written by Martin Krumm: http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex_gantt_package.php